# How to write a script to insert large amounts of data in mysql?

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a database project where one of the requirements is that we must have 100,000 tuples of data. We originally were looking for general population data where each individual is represented by a tuple, but we quickly found out that sort of data isn't really available. No worries, we can create our own data!

So basically I need to write a basic script to just iterate through every tuple and insert basic stuff, like an `ID(Just number them 1-100000)`, a set of random initials, a random income, and a random occupation from a list of 6 or so. Is this possible in mysql? I am really not excited about writing 100000 `INSERT` commands

Comment: autoincremented id can be handled by mysql. Other than that your problem becomes a much simpler one. Find out how to generate random values and then how to connect to a db in the language of your choice(php,py) in order to insert them

Comment: as you are inserting random number why not use for loop. in the loop you will have a insert query which will run for 100000 times

Comment: Some form of effort is needed before people will take your question seriously. Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry if I came across as lazy. I have been googling all morning. I am very new to Sql and databases in general, so I'm not exactly sure what I am looking for. Wasn't looking for someone's code to copy or anything, I was just looking for a concept to research further!

Comment: So I can use a for loop to do this? I was under the impression sql didn't have for loops. Or would I be writing this in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for i in range(1, 1000000)
    initials = ?
    income = ?
    occupation = ?
    sql = "insert into t(initials, income, occupation) values ('{0}', {1}, '{2}')".format(initials, income, occupation)
    curs.execute(sql)
```

I'm not sure what values you want for the various fields.  You can create lists of acceptable values and then use `random()` to choose from a list . . . or use `random()` to generate a numeric value.

It will take a little time to insert 1,000,000 rows.  If this is an issue, write the data to a file and use `load data infile`.